# A Python IDE with Debugging and iPython Integration?

Tags: python, debugging, ide, ipython, pdb

Does anyone know of a python IDE that has iPython as the interpreter?

Using the standard interpreter just drives me nuts, as I've just grown to love using iPython and all the features it provides.  To be honest, I'd rather code with a simple text editor + ipython than an IDE, but I love being able to set breakpoints with a click of a mouse, etc., so I'd like to combine both.

Sorry if there's something out there and this is common knowledge.  Any information/tips you can provide  is GREATLY appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Which OS? (Although, come to think of it, I'd be interested in hearing about answers for any system)

Comment: Either Linux or Windows (preferably the latter... use my laptop and mount through ExpanDrive or Dokan SSHFS).

Comment: Update: I've taken to just using ipython and pdb, but pdb still doesn't have the nice "whos" function that is in the ipython shell.  Is there something similar to this when using pdb?  Just looking for a way to examine the variables at a given point in the code....

Answer (score 4):

Btw, I've seen Spyder (formerly Pydee), and that indeed will have iPython integration in September, but it still lacks a debugger.  ::sigh::

Answer (score 3):

As of 28/04/2012 [Spyder](http://code.google.com/p/spyderlib/) provides a debugger and iPython(v 0.10.2) integration and [Python Tools for Visual Studio](http://pytools.codeplex.com/) provides a debugger and iPython(v 0.12) integration.

Answer (score 3):

Sypder(2) comes closest to what you may need. I have used this for some time and falling in love with it. It comes with handy code completion, code analysis and other utilities. It was in my ubuntu software centre, ready for a one click install :). 
give it a shot

https://code.google.com/p/spyderlib/

Answer (score 2):

[pudb](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pudb) is a full-screen, text-mode "console" debugger with iPython integration.

I don't know of other Python debuggers (or IDEs) which integrate with iPython, which seems to be the core of your request.

Answer (score 2):

> IPython can be used as the backend for the PyDev interactive console.

This quote is from the instructions written in August 2011 by Fabio Zadrozny on his [blog](http://pydev.blogspot.com/2011/08/ipython-pydev.html).  He is currently maintaining PyDev.

Answer (score 0):

http://pydev.org for eclipse is great and debugger works well. Not sure what ipython provides but the interactive terminal in pydev is pretty good (completion , etc)

Comment: Indeed, pydev is an excellent Python IDE and it provides python shell, but it is not even close to IPython's capabilities. Pydev developer once said something about IPython's design that makes it extremely hard to integrate IPython in PyDev.

Comment: See @Kews's answer pydev now can use ipython as the shell

Answer (score 0):

Closest I've found is using GEdit with the ipython plugin from

http://code.google.com/p/gedit-ipythonconsole/

Personally I use pycharm most of the time and have found that I can get SOME IPython functions by executing code from
http://folk.uio.no/steikr/doc/python/ipython/node9.html

```
import IPython.Shell
IPython.Shell.start().mainloop()
```

If you are a PyCharm user and want to see IPython support then vote up the ticket at
http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/PY-4504?projectKey=PY